# Getting a list of li using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to get a list of the li on this website http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/ but it doesn't do what I want it to do.

this is what I'm currently using

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Your\\ChromeDriver\\Path");

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setHeadless(false);

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    driver.get("http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/");

    List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul#shop-scroller")); 

    System.out.println(allElements.size());

    for(WebElement e : allElements) {
        System.out.println(e.getText());
    }

}
```

and all it returns is

```
new
```

Edit: I'm trying to get the ul in the div with the shop class

Comment: I've looked at several other people who were trying to achieve the same thing as me, but it didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Please give a [mcve].

Comment: @Code-Apprentice ok sorry, I'll edit the post

Comment: Is this better? @Code-Apprentice

Comment: Why is your code looking for `ul` when you want `li` elements?

Comment: I was thinking if I can get the ul then I could also get the list of li. It might be the wrong mind set though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to print the ul inner html (or get its attributes such as id and style), you should do like:

```
  driver.get("http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/");
            List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul#shop-scroller"));
   WebElement ul = allElements.get(0);

   // getting ul data
   System.out.println("ul id = " + ul.getAttribute("id"));
   System.out.println("ul style = " + ul.getAttribute("style"));
   System.out.println("inner html: ");
   System.out.println(ul.getAttribute("innerHTML"));


   // getting all li in ul
   List<WebElement> liList = ul.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
   for(WebElement li: liList) {
       System.out.println("li class = " + li.getAttribute("class"));
       System.out.println("li style = " + li.getAttribute("style"));
       System.out.println("inner html: ");
       System.out.println(li.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
       System.out.println("---------");
      // getting the image  in li
     List<WebElement> imgList = li.findElements(By.tagName("img"));
        WebElement img = imgList.get(0);                
       // do something
```

}

In fact, there is a "new" text in the span of each li tag. That's why the method getText() prints "new".

Comment: I want to loop through each of the images in the scroller and click on each one individually.

Comment: I've updated the code to show how can get each image individually.

Comment: how would I go about clicking and opening the page. When I try doing it, it says that "element is not visible".

Comment: Try to get the total number of li in the ul (liList.size()).
Then, save this value in a variable (such as int total). Doing this way, you can access the li elements using an index. After that, make a request on the main page each time you need to click on an image of a li (liList.get(index)), until index < total.

Answer (score 1):

If you observe the *HTML* of the website `http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/` the data you are looking for i.e. **skate**, **jackets**, **sweatshirts**, etc are contained as `class` attribute of the `<li>` tags. To get a list of the `<li>` tags you can use the following code block :

```
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul#shop-scroller li")); 
System.out.println(allElements.size());
for(WebElement e : allElements) {
    System.out.println(e.getAttribute("class"););
}
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I was looking inside each of the li and I see the URL in an "a href" tag. I tried getting the contents but it returns the whole line. This is what I used `WebElement link = li.findElement(By.tagName("a"));
         
         System.out.println(link.getAttribute("href"));` how can I go about only getting the text inside the href part.

Comment: nvm I figured it out! Thanks to everyone who helped!

Comment: @DebajanB I couldn't do more than 1. I upvoted your post, but it will show after I get 15 rep. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone who helped me find a solution. here is my final code for anyone else that comes across this problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\WebStuff\\chromedriver.exe");

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setHeadless(false);

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    driver.get("http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/");

    List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul#shop-scroller")); 

    WebElement ul = allElements.get(0);

    List<WebElement> liList = ul.findElements(By.tagName("li"));

     for(WebElement li: liList) {
    /*       System.out.println("li class = " + li.getAttribute("class"));
           System.out.println("li style = " + li.getAttribute("style"));
           System.out.println("inner html: ");
           System.out.println(li.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
           System.out.println("---------");
           */
           WebElement link = li.findElement(By.tagName("a"));

           System.out.println(link.getAttribute("href"));

           driver.get(link.getAttribute("href"));

           return;

       }



}
```

Comment: I am happy you found the solution. It was a interesting discussion.